# How can I remap keys in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: remapping

I am using an Asus C200 chromebook running Ubuntu 16.04, and I want to know how to remap the F10 button to Volume up, and F9 button to volume down.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
cd /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbol
```

Make a copy of the file `srvr_ctrl` somewhere you can restore it if you want

Open it with your favorite editor using `sudo`

```
sudo vim srvr_ctrl
```

Change the lines

```
symbols[Group1]= [ F10, F10, F10, F10, XF86_Switch_VT_10 ]
```

To

```
symbols[Group1]= [ XF86AudioRaiseVolume, F10, F10, F10, XF86_Switch_VT_10 ]
```

And

```
symbols[Group1]= [ F9, F9, F9, F9, XF86_Switch_VT_9 ]
```

To

```
symbols[Group1]= [ XF86AudioLowerVolume, F9, F9, F9, XF86_Switch_VT_9 ]
```

Now save, exit, and re-login to your account.